# incorrect value: unknown namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soa, sap-basis

I am trying to consume  external Web service(WSDL FILE) in sap for data integration when I tried to create client proxy in SAP and gives service provider webservice URL  **http://172.31.3.48:8717/?wsdl** it gives me proxy generation error:

> Exception occurred in library handler
>
> incorrect value: unknown namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema

I am facing this error in just in this file which provided by my services provider , except this all of the WSDL file generated successfully one the file which generated successfully is this http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL.

Your help will be appreciated.

Given below is my WSDL file which giving me error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
                  xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
                  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
      <s:element name="GetData">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="user" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="pass" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fromdate" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="todate" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetDataResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetDataResult">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:element ref="s:schema" />
                  <s:any />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetDataSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetDataSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WSCRPL9001Soap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetDataSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetDataSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WSCRPL9001Soap" type="tns:WSCRPL9001Soap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetData" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="WSCRPL9001Soap12" type="tns:WSCRPL9001Soap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetData" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="WSCRPL9001">
    <wsdl:port name="WSCRPL9001Soap" binding="tns:WSCRPL9001Soap">
      <soap:address location="http://172.31.3.48:8717/WS-CRPL-9001.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="WSCRPL9001Soap12" binding="tns:WSCRPL9001Soap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://172.31.3.48:8717/WS-CRPL-9001.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something seems off with this element. An element that directly references the schema is pretty strange to me - I've never seen such structure:

```
    <s:element name="GetDataResponse">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetDataResult">
                    <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                            <s:element ref="s:schema" />
                            <s:any />
                        </s:sequence>
                    </s:complexType>
                </s:element>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
```

I've validated your WSDL in Eclipse - see what Eclipse says for this WSDL:

*Error resolving component 's:schema'. It was detected that 's:schema' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///WSDLTEST.wsdl'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 's:schema' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///WSDL.wsdl'.*

Try removing `<s:element ref="s:schema" />` line altogether and see if it works for you. Or describe the sequence element by element the way it's been done for the request GetData.

Comment: Hi plamen thank you so much for your reply and your comment I do remove <s:element ref="s:schema" /> from my wsdl file it generated successfully, but now it can't reference the file which it have to reference, kindly also give me a way to use correct way of this statement <s:element ref="s:schema" />  so it can reference able. i don't have so much idea how wsdl actually works because it's not in my domain , this file is provided by my service provide and i just want to consume this in my sap environment, so your help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer helpful, kindly please mark it as such. Unfortunately there's no way of telling what you need to reference from a distance with only the info you have provided. It depends on your specific use case and what the service must return as results. You should define the response the same way the request is defined in your wsdl, unless you have an external xsd.

Comment: basically the scenario  is in this file it takes username and pasw after finding the username pasw it redirects to the another file which have actual data elements , so i want ask that how can i correct this statement <s:element ref="s:schema" />

Comment: @Shazar The technical contract (wsdl in this case) must be in place before consumption of the service. It is not negotiated at runtime. So I suggest you make a manual  request trough SOAP UI and see what gets returned as response.

Comment: sorry plamen petrov, I couldn't understand what you are saying would you please elaborate it more because it don't  have any expertise in xml and wsdl concepts i already said that i am a sap developer its not in my domain i just consume it to integrate webservies, you help needed in this if you edit my wsdl file, i have my wsdl file on live ip which is this http://202.83.160.22/WS-crpl-9001/ws-crpl-9001.asmx?wsdl , if you go to http://wsdlbrowser.com/ this link and give this link of my wsdl file http://202.83.160.22/WS-crpl-9001/ws-crpl-9001.asmx?wsdl you can see the ref file in it, help me

Comment: OK, I will try to check it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75001/discussion-between-plamen-petrov-and-shazar).

Comment: hi Plamen petrov ,sorry to disturb you again, do you know anything about this "SoapFaultCode:3  SOAP header To was not understood" error. it happens when i test this web service after giving username and psw etc in parameter in response it giving me this error

Comment: It is related to the MustUnderstand attribute set to 1. Try without that attrbute. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712616/consuming-wsdl-using-c-sharp-but-getting-error-soap-header-to-was-not-understo and here: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_header.asp

Comment: where i have to set this attribute to 1? I mean should i tell the service provide to set this attribute to 1 or I have to (consuming side) set this attribute to 1, if yes than where?